# Convert Textbox value to int and also check for is it Empty or Not

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, html

I am trying to update record of a person in a gridview  when i am input into textbox(tAge) it shows me an exception **Input string was not in a correct format.** i had tried a lot of codes but won't work please help me out.And **thanks** in advance.
here is my code to update Person details

```
protected void UpdateRecord(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int personID = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    int intResult = 0;
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox tFN = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFName");
    TextBox tLN = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtLName");
    TextBox tAge = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAge");
    // instantiate BAL
    PersonBAL pBAL = new PersonBAL();
    PersonBO person = new PersonBO();
    try
    {
        person.PersonID = personID;
        person.FirstName = tFN.Text;
        person.LastName = tLN.Text;
        person.Age = Int32.Parse(tAge.Text);
        //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.Trim(tFN.Text)))
        if (tFN.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Name can't be Blank";
        }
        else if (tLN.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "LastName can't be Blank";
        }
        else if (tAge.Text.Trim()=="")
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Age can't be Blank";
        }
        else
        {
            intResult = pBAL.Update(person); 
        if (intResult > 0 && tFN.Text != "")
        {
            string message = "Updated Successfully!";
            string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "');";
            script += "window.location = '";
            script += Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            script += "'; }";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
        }
        //else if( tFN.Text == "")
        //{
        //} 
        else
        {
            string message = "Already Exist!";
            string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "');";
            script += "window.location = '";
            script += Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            script += "'; }";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
            //lblMessage.Text = message.ToString();
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    { 
        lblMessage.Text = ee.Message.ToString(); 
    }

    finally
    {
        person = null;
        pBAL = null;
    }
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    // Refresh the list
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: This is web forms code not MVC!

Comment: Try `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tFN.Text)) return;`, or if you want to handle the case: `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tFN.Text)) { ..do something if there is empty or null value... };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to check the `Text` property first before assigning it to the appropriate values. For the conversion there exist a nice method `TryParse` it returns a `bool` and will only parse if the format is correct.

```
try
{
    // ask whether it is blank or full of spaces
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tFN.Text))
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Name can't be Blank";
    }
    else 
    {
        person.FirstName = tFN.Text;
    }

    // do the same again for the last name
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tLN.Text))
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Name can't be Blank";
    }
    else 
    {
        person.FirstName = tLN.Text;
    }


    // use TryParse for the age
    int p_age;
    if (Int.TryParse(tAge.Text, out p_age))
    {
        person.Age = p_age;
    }
    else 
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Age is in incorrect Format";
    }

   ....
```